# Opening a flsh file exe in web page and in chrome browser with the help of onlick

Tags: google-chrome, flash, web, browser, exe

Trying to open a flash exe file in the chrome browser only as it is supported by mac, windows and Linux operating systems, So what I am trying when I click on a link it opens a webpage in which I could embed or give the link of start.exe file to run it. How to make it possible, if anybody has an idea or way to do it Please share.

Comment: You need to export as SWF file from Flash (choose **export movie** option). Through SWF format is how Flash content is displayed browser (the Flash Player plugin will load your Flash content). EXE is a **Windows** application file!! Double-click the the .exe to open it. Don't try to open in a browser or other systems like Mac or Linux.

Comment: PS: If you meant you have an SWF file to show in browser then look at : **https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_embed** for basic example... **note*: SWF must be **embedded** in HTML tag, not just direct file link in address like as possible for a jpeg or mp3.